# periodic reccurent sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given this reccurent sequence :
{ $a_{0}$  $\in$ R ;

$a_{n+1}$ =  $a_{n}$ -  ($1/a_{n}$)

How can we determine  $a_{0}$  in order to get a periodic sequence ?

Comment: Period? Do you mean limit?

Comment: The sequence is not always well-defined. Check what happens if $a_0=0$, or $a_0=1$ for example.

Comment: no not limit , for example : a0=1, a1=2, a2=1, a3=2 , .... this is a periodic sequence with period p=2 , see this link for more details [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_sequence)

Comment: For any given a0 such that the sequence is well-defined

Comment: @meh98 Why do you think the sequence can be periodic ?

Comment: if it 's periodic or not , how can we proove it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solve $f(f(x))=x$ to get a sequence with period $2$, ($x =\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$), solve $f(f(f(x)))=x$ to get a sequence period $3$, etc.

Comment: Any link for the demonstrartion